# How to properly set the G1GC options for a server with 22G heap

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm, jvm-hotspot

I’m setting up a new JAVA server, the heap size is set to 22G, and would use the G1GC algorithm. I've read all the oracle documents, and believe this is what we need, but still have a few questions:

1> What -XX:G1HeapRegionSize should be ? Must the number be a power of two? If so, should I set 8M to get 2816 regions, or set 16M to get 1408 regions ?

2> Do you think we should explicitly set -XX:ParallelGCThreads and -XX:ConcGCThreads ? If they are omitted, will they be set to a default number according to the server logical processors ? Or just be set to a fixed number ?

3> What about the below options, is there anything I missed ? Since it's the first time we use the G1GC, so I've no idea if we need set other G1 related options, since they all have a recommended default value. (described in https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/g1_gc_tuning.html)

// common options

> -Xms22G -Xmx22G -Xss1024K

// G1 options

> -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=500 -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16

// logs

> -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
>
> -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintGCApplicationConcurrentTime -XX:-PrintCommandLineFlags

4> Do you think it possible to do the things roughly right for the first time? I mean without memory overflow or exhausted. Or do you think we will always have to tune the parameters more carefully to get things right for several times ?

5> Any other suggestions ?

It's a bit long, thanks for your reading. Any help will be much appreciate. Thank you!

Comment: What makes you think that you *should* set specific options? The only options you really need, is `-XX:+UseG1GC` and `-Xmx22G`. You should only change an option, if you really have a reason to deviate from the defaults. Your questions indicate that you don’t have such reasons, in fact, it looks like you never tried to run your server with the defaults. You are wasting your time with *premature optimization*. And obsolete options. E.g., Java 8 has no *Perm Gen*, so any *Perm Gen* related options are useless.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help.  I will do more test on the server and see the results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting from the document you linked to:

> The G1 GC is an adaptive garbage collector **with defaults that enable it to work efficiently without modification**.

So, the most obvious suggestion ... based on the documentation itself ... is to run the JVM without any GC tuning.  Just give it the heap size, and select the GC:

```
-Xmx22G -XX:+UseG1GC
```

The G1GC is *designed* so that you can use it that way and get good performance.

If it works well enough, that's all you need to do.  If you see performance problems, then start looking into tuning ... based on the nature of the problems that you are seeing.

Tuning *just for the sake of it* is a waste of time.

Tuning when you don't (yet) have any idea of the performance problems is a bit like target shooting with a blindfold on.  You are liable to make things worse than if you did nothing.

Finally, the "optimal" GC settings will depend on various aspects of your application and your workload, and the goal of your tuning.  Anything we might suggest would be pure guesswork.

Comment: OK. Thanks for your help.  I will do more test on the server and see the results.

Comment: Finally, I'm relatively satified with below JVM options -Xms20g -Xmx20g -Xss1024K -XX:MetaspaceSize=128M -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:MaxGCPauseMillis=200 -XX:+UseStringDeduplication -XX:+UnlockExperimentalVMOptions -XX:G1NewSizePercent=40 Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

The optimal G1GC options depend heavily on your application and on the infrastructure on which it runs. To get the best performance, you'll need to test out various combinations and see which performs better in your environment. You can use a free tuning tool like [Optimizer Studio](https://concertio.com/) that can tune those options (as well as the rest of the JVM parameters) automatically.

Answer (score 0):

There is no perfect set of GC flags can be applied for all applications.
We can try with default values first and use tools ([gceasy](https://gceasy.io/), [gcviewer](https://github.com/chewiebug/GCViewer)) to analyse the GC logs and see what can be improved further.

Here is my notes when tuning G1GC, hope you can find useful info there
[How Garbage First Garbage Collector (G1GC) affected the performance of our back-end](https://medium.com/@hoan.nguyen.it/how-did-g1gc-tuning-flags-affect-our-back-end-web-app-c121d38dfe56)

Comment: I've read the article. It did helps me a lot, because I also have the same concern ------ what if the HIOP 45 is almost the same with the server common MEM usage? Will the GC takes too much of the CPU time then? I have many concerns because, this is a very busy sever, and always need the engineer team to do the change for me. So I don't want it die very often during the GC update. 

I agree with you guys' suggestion, we should first test with the default option. And then tune it according to the GC logs.